# Using github repo in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, plivo

I'm working with apps script and the plivo api (https://www.plivo.com/docs/sms/api/message#list-all-messages). I'd like to be able to use the plivo node sdk (https://www.plivo.com/docs/sdk/server/node-sdk/) inside apps script. Is there a way to install this or use this from github or some other source directly?

Comment: Have you looked at using [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) to develop locally and then push to your apps script project?

Comment: No..`````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

***In a summary you can't install or use plivo by using Apps Script***.

You can use [your own libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#using_a_library) or a [shared library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#sharing_a_library). Third party (external and not shared) libraries in Google Apps Script are not allowed directly.

As per the [Google Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) says `Google Apps Script is a rapid application development platform that makes it fast and easy to create business applications that integrate with G Suite`. Apps Script goal is mainly interact with other Google Services/APIs.

### Why using third party libraries is not allowed/recommended?

It's possible to use the `eval` and `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` function in order to get the content of a specific JS and execute it like:

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://URL/javascript.js').getContentText());
```

However, it's adding more computing time when it comes to run an Apps Script and depending on your kind of user there's a [limit to successfully execute a script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).

External services like plivo or another VOIP services are not allowed due to the reasons I mentioned above. As a workaround I'd suggest to take a look into GCP products like [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) or [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) and make use of your third party library from [there](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects).